# Show empty cell in excel when reference cell is empty

Tags: excel

I used @Jeeped's formula and it worked great but now I'm getting #Value when the reference cell is empty. I've tried adding other coding such as IF statements but nothing works and I don't know why it started in the first place. Very strange.

```
=INDEX(Building!$A:$A,IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$D:$D, 0),IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$E:$E, 0),IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$F:$F, 0), "nowhere"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another IFERROR to the front of the formula, like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Building!$A:$A,IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$D:$D, 0),IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$E:$E, 0),IFERROR(MATCH(D14, Building!$F:$F, 0), "nowhere")))),"")
```

Comment: Perfect, @SincereApathy. Thank you